# Material of an object (nodes) wont load unless I duplicate the object

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, eevee-render-engine

Here is a screen recording showing the issue I have:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/owo4yfxuyfdvwfa/BlenderHelp.mp4?dl=0

This is my situation. I troubleshot for a long time and could find anything online, so I'd love help from you all. I'm really new so baby language would be appreciated. This also happens across different projects but only when I'm using nodes. It might be node wrangler that's the problem, but I don't know. Thank you very much in advance!

The blend file is here:
https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/QXKszBWO

Comment: Please describe what your desired result is, what you do, what result you get and how it is different from your expectations and form a clear question.

Comment: Also share clear screenshots without clipping essential parts of your screen. It is best to capture the whole Blender interface because it contains various settings, Blender version and so on. You should share the screenshots and text inside your question to remain and be possible to discover for people having similar issues in the future - links might stop working, only video is not enough for it to be useful for the community in the future. These things will improve your chances of getting a good answer faster.

Comment: Oh, this is really odd :). Would you mind [sharing your file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)?

Comment: Heres the file as you asked https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/QXKszBWO still found no solutions.

Comment: What version of Blender are you using? I'm on 2.82.7 on Windows 10 and the materials are showing up properly when I opened the blend file.

Comment: I'm using v2.82, ill try downloading the newer version. Would it in any way be because of my laptop being slow?

Comment: That depends on your hardware. if your drivers are out of date or your hardware don't quite meet the system requirements, that could be the source of the issue.

Comment: So with more troubleshooting... it works in cycles without a problem. EEVEE has issues, however... basically all I got. Any way to somehow increase the detail (or something else) of the viewport / render other than the samples? Might help me and my crappy computer.

Comment: @Bro_Dog I'm not quite sure tbh...Bump maps are supported in both render engines, so there shouldn't be any issues. I'd just double-check that all your drivers are up to date. I don't really have much experience dealing with older hardware as I started using Blender after I updated my hardware :/